# Silverstripe 3: How to translate Datas Objects?

Tags: translation, multilingual, silverstripe

Is it possible to translate Dataobjects in Silverstripe 3?

I use  this Module:
http://www.silverstripe.org/translatable-module/

In my config if have the following defined:

```
Object::add_extension('SiteTree', 'Translatable');
Object::add_extension('News', 'Translatable');
```

The first line is the normal extension for translating pages and the second one is supposed to make the Data Objects (in this case News) translatable.

I manage the News as DataObjects in a ModelAdmin where I can add a News DataObject. There is even existing a Tab "Translation". When I click on it I see a Dropdown where I can select my defined Language and a "Create" Button. The only thing is that pressing the "Create" button has no effect at all.

Anyone an idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The short (and unhelpful) answer is that the Translatable extension can't do this yet. It's currently quite tightly coupled to SiteTree.

If you're using SS 2.4.x have a look at [setting up a multilingual site](http://www.balbuss.com/setting-up-a-multilingual-site/) for some options.

For non-SiteTree translations, have a look into the [TranslatableDataObject extension](https://github.com/unclecheese/TranslatableDataObject).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already had a look at your links. I also tried this one https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-translatablemodeladmin but it seems it´s not compatible with SS3. 

Finally I ended up adding a Locale Field by myself to the DataObjects. So I can filter the output by the value saved in it.

Answer (score 2):

Now it is possible to translate DataObjects with SS3. Check this project https://github.com/bummzack/translatable-dataobject